# parallel pool constant on Matlab

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

On Matlab, I built a parallel pool constant from a cell( it size is 55x1) which contains large matrix's, and it took 5 minutes. When i don't use the code, the parallel pool shuts down and i loose my parallel pool constant.

My question is if it's possible to load it like a variable that is saved and then imported for an other use so i will not need to build it each time and wait 5 minutes ( I tried with save and Load but it seems that the parallel pool constant is invalid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, MATLAB Parallel Pool will automatically shut down after being idle for 30 minutes. If you create a parallel pool with

```
>> p = parpool(2)
```

you can view the remaining time with

```
>> p.IdleTimeout

ans =

    30
```

which means, you have 30 minutes remaining. You are free to increase this time, so the MATLAB pool doesn't shut down too soon. There are multiple possible ways:

1. If you have already created the pool, you can change the remaining time by setting `p.IdleTimeout` to the appropriate value, e.g.

   ```
   p.IdleTimeout = 60
   ```
2. When creating a new parallel pool, you can specify the timeout directly

   ```
   p = parpool(2, 'IdleTimeout', 90)
   ```
3. The default option can be set in the preferences, as described in the [MATLAB documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parallel-preferences.html).

You can specify any time in minutes, e.g. 60 minutes, or even longer, e.g. 8h = 480 minutes for a whole work-day. You can also specify the `'IdleTimeout'` to be `inf`, i.e. infinity. This means that the pool will *not* shutdown automatically, and you will have to do that manually by calling `delete(p)`. In the GUI you can do the same by removing the corresponding tick in the check box.